# how to include the jquery file in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the value of checkbox in chrome extension using jquery, but it
is giving me error:

> "$ is not defined"

I download the jquery file and save in folder and giving path of jquery file in `manifest.json` but, still same error is coming. So I want to know what is correct way to include jquery file.

I write like this :

```
{
    "name": "Chrome Extension Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Chrome extension to investigate Etsy product listings.",
    "permissions": [
        "storage",

    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/get_started16.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "background.html",
        "icons": {
            "16": "images/get_started16.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Seller Tools"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js", "js/jquery/jquery.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "manifest_version": 2

}
```

The whole code I am writing in background.js, but when I write
Jquery(including $) for any functionality so it's giving me error that "$
is not defined" and I am facing very difficult. It is also not
allowing me to write .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it almost correctly, the only thing you need to fix is the script order. You are using jQuery in your content script, so jQuery should be loaded first:

```
{
    "name": "Chrome Extension Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Chrome extension to investigate Etsy product listings.",
    "permissions": [
        "storage",

    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/get_started16.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "background.html",
        "icons": {
            "16": "images/get_started16.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Seller Tools"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "js/jquery/jquery.js", "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "manifest_version": 2

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can include it in the head tag of your HTML document and not in the .js or .json file

```
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

Then you can use jquery any where in your HTML document

Comment: Specifically for Chrome extension it's not enough - jQuery indeed must be referenced from a manifest file there.